# Python Pandas pd.read_csv numbers on some of the rows end with .0 while other rows in the same colum do not end with .0

Tags: pandas

A year ago there was someone with a similar issue, but it does not work for me.
When I read the dataframe, some of the phone numbers end with .0 while others do not in the same column.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Member_Contact_Info.csv', dtype={'Priority_Cell':str, 'Priority_Home':str})
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df
```

Sample Result:

Jane   Doe 5105551212    2015552121

John   Doe 5105552222.0  5105551234

Janet  Doe 5105551111    5105554444.0

and so on....

```
df = pd.read_csv('Member_Contact_Info.csv', dtype=str)
```

Has the same result.

When I open the Member_Contact_Info.csv in Excel, the following .0 do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try `na_values`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Member_Contact_Info.csv', dtype=str, na_values='')
```